# How to make controls looks bigger in gnome 3 for a better look and feel on HDPI screens?

Tags: fedora, resolution

While using Ubuntu I can scale controls (in the Displays tool) using a float number: [image: Ubuntu Displays tool] which is accurate enough to provide a decent user experience.

Now, I would like to have the same on Fedora for example but when running gnome-tweak-tools (cause the Displays tool is not really the same on a Raw Fedora Gnome3) only integers are accepted which lead to 2 extremes: controls are whether too small and hence are barely readable or too big and then the system as a whole cannot be really used.

Is there any way to get something similar on Fedora (accurate ratio to scale controls)?

Comment: I don't think you can unless you [also use `xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#GNOME). I'd love to be proven wrong...

Answer (score 3):

I use the font scaling factor setting in `gnome-tweak-tools` to scale the UI on HiDPI screens. 
It gives me finer control over the scaling.

It works because Gnome automatically scales the UI elements to fit around the text in GTK 3 programs.

If you want even finer control, you can set each element types font size manually in the same section of the `gnome-tweak-tool`.